# Sinônimos de tags (object e es6)

Tags: debate, tags, tags-sinônimas

Vejo que temos a tag [`es6`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/es6/info) e [`ecmascript-6`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/info). Creio que `es6` deveria ser sinônimo de `ecmascript-6`.

---

E um novo sinônimo para [`objetos`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/objetos/info). Estava vendo o site e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/404425/69296) pergunta contém [`object`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/object/info) **e** `objeto`. Creio que `object` (e `objects`) deveriam ser sinônimos de `objetos`.

---

- `es6` ⇒ `ecmascript-6`
- `object` ⇒ `objetos`

O que acham?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feito para as duas e ainda a ES5.